# 'A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.', how to resolve this

Tags: flutter

assert(
data != null,
'A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.',
),
textSpan = null

The following assertion was thrown building Consumer(dependencies: [MediaQuery, _InheritedProviderScope<LocationProvider?>, _InheritedTheme, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#42a4f]]):
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 444 pos 10: 'data != null'

Comment: provide a non-null string (for instance empty string `''`) instead of `null`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Text(yourText!=null?yourText!:'')
```

Where yourText is the string you have given to the text.

Comment: assert(
         data != null,
         'A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.',
       ),
       textSpan = null;